# Bad positioned text with display inline in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a title in a div toolbar next to some pictures. The problem is that my text is not well placed, it should be at least on top of the toolbar but instead it is at bottom and doesn't move.
I would like it to be in the vertical middle at left near the pictures.

Here is a codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fDojK

And a picture :
[image]

Here is the html part of the title bar:

```
<div id="bar" >
<div id="picturesmenu">
    <img src='images/back.jpg' alt='back' />
    <img src='images/home.jpg' alt='home' />
    <img src='images/reload.jpg' alt='reload' />
</div>
<div id="titlemenu">Main</div>
</div>
<div id="body">
...
```

And style :

```
#bar
{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-left:10px;
    border-bottom:2px solid white;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#picturesmenu
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
}

#bar img
{
    border:3px solid white;
    width:40px;
    margin:2px;
}

#titlemenu
{
    margin:0;
    padding-left:20px;
    height:100%;
    display:inline;
    font-size:20pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
}

#bar span
{
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:200px;
    font-size:20pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;

}
```

I tried vertical align and margin but the "Main" text doesn't move...

Thanks in advance before I change anything into tables ;)

**[EDIT]**

Thank you all for your answers ! I didn't thought about handling the alignment of the content (#titlemenu) instead of the container (#bar), it's not very logical...

Comment: set `vertical-align: top;` to `#titlemenu` - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejumq **and** you can also use `line-height: 0.9;` to achieve better top position - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gudfe

Comment: negative top margin value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work the vertical align for both `#picturesmenu` and `#titlemenu` and remove the padding left for that title if you want it to the left. Then work with `inline-block` elements. Like this:

**EDITED WITH CROSS-BROWSER CODE**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:black;
}
#bar {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-left:10px;
    border-bottom:2px solid white;
    display:block;
}
#picturesmenu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#bar img {
    border:3px solid white;
    width:40px;
    margin:2px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:40px;
    height:50px;
}
#titlemenu {
    margin:0;
    padding-left:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:20pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border:2px solid white;
    text-align:center;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
}
.picitem {
    height:70%;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    border:2px solid white;
}
.textitem {
    underline:none;
    color:black;
    font-size:16pt;
    color:white;
}
```

I have forked your [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/duvwF)

However, a way better approach would be to give #bar a `display:block` property and then add `inline-block` to everything inside, but if you want it to work as in your description, there you go

Comment: you must be using Chrome which is becoming worse and worse with every new version. For Chrome you have to remove the vertical-align in elements to the side of higher elements, I have made a new version at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/duvwF that works cross-browser by cleaning unneeded elements

Comment: +1) Oops! you're right, I was using Chrome and my solution doesn't work on firefox, I didn't notice it lol. You're using `width: 40px;` twice to `#bar img` but it works great. - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FKfny

Comment: @MaryMelody: as a matter of fact, your comment was incredibly useful, Sometimes I forget about cross-browser compatibility and your comment made me realize about that, so it was a collaborative effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to the `#titlemenu` in `CSS`

```
padding:10px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
```

By `vertical-align:top`, the block gets aligned to the top of the parent`div` and you set `padding` to fit the height of the block to the height of the parent `div`

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kEihl)